# How to add uiview in uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hope all of you'll be fine.
I have a little issue in my application. I have a tableview with custom-cell. In my custom-cell class i made a uiview

```html
    UIView* cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.frame];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:cellView];
```

Problem is uiview is not fitting in my cell frame properly. Cellforrow is as :

```html
- (SummaryViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    SummaryViewCell *cell = (SummaryViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[SummaryViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  return cell;
}
```

I have tried initWithFrame:self.contentView.frame] but same problem happened (uiview appear in cell but cover only half of the cell), I also have tried cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width and same as for height) but failed. Need your valuable advise and ideas. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where did you creating subview?
Try to do it in -layoutSubviews method.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

UIView* cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.frame];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:cellView];
}
```

All frames for subviews are already calculated inside this method and you should receive correct width\height for your subview.

Comment: Fantastic and fabulous solution. . . thanks alot @4esterUA. I have wasted my lot of time (10 am to 03 pm). You saved my rest of the day. Many thanks and best regards from the deep of my heart.

Comment: I'm glad that was able to help you. Please, mark my answer as correct, it would be a good thanks.

Comment: Sure sir/madam. . . i already have tried to do so but message showed "You Can mark answer after 59 sec". Sure i will mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting clip to bounds

```
[cellView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your response, 4estrUA's answer solved my problem.

Comment: I used it in my custom tableview cell.