# Dynamic TableView Cell Heights Incorrect Until After Scrolling (iOS 8) - full screenshots attached

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

**EDIT**

*Built a new sample project from scratch and the dynamic tableview cell height is working flawlessly. I then tried to replicate by trimming down my project to it's bare minimum and it's STILL broken (first few cells buggy). Attaching full project for both working and not working examples. Project/code literally looks 99% identical and for the love of me can't figure out where the 1% difference is. The only thing that is popping out at me is that I used different size classes (wAny hAny vs wCompact hRegular but I can't imagine that would do anything given I'm testing in portrait only*

Working project:
[image]

Not working project:
[image]

```
WORKING (new project from scratch):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EIkjmOj3ImWXZjVFZMYXZmVGc/view?usp=sharing

NOT WORKING (my project, cleaned up to it's bare minimum)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EIkjmOj3ImMGRNOXU2RlNkWEk/view?usp=sharing
```

---

Have scoured the web trying to understand what is going on, but for some reason my cell heights are incorrect until I scroll past the prototype cells.

Upon initial load:
[image]

And after scrolling past each cell:
[image]

Background colors:

        `cell.postTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];`

Not doing anything too fancy here: just a prototype cell, a subview, and three labels (username, timestamp, text).

Below screenshots highlight my constraints in Storyboard:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I pull data from Parse, and am reloading my data while setting tableView layout

`[self.tableView setNeedsLayout];
            [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
            [self.tableView reloadData];`

And lastly my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self postCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)postCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *PostCellIdentifier = @"PostCell";
    PostCell *cell = (PostCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PostCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configurePostCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've seen this problem too. Does my answer here help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787552/ios-8-auto-height-cell-not-correct-height-at-first-load/27787736#27787736

Comment: Nope, that's a no go for me unfortunately. Added to my custom cell, same result

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same symptoms.

Comment: I did - turned out my issue was pretty specific but I just had to change my size class to wAny and hAny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the problem why it is not working. I downloaded the Projects which were uploaded to drive by you, and do modifications in it. And found the issue that you use **compact Regular** size classes which causes error. After converting your size classes to **Any, Any** it works fine and perfect.so the key of the solution is change **wCompact hRegular** to **wAny hAny.** There is no change in code.

That was initial answer.

Detailed Answer :

1) for the size classes first read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html) document of apple.

2) In your broken demo the size classes are selected as given below :

[image]

This indicates that you selected specific view like compact width and regular height means this auto layout will only work in specific iPhone portrait orientation.

> Compact Width | Regular Height combination specifies layout changes
>   that apply only to sizes resembling iPhone devices in portrait
>   orientation.
>
> The control wCompact hRegular indicates the compact width and regular
>   height size classes.

I used below size classes and also in your working project i can be able to see below size classes :

[image]

In this Size classes it's working fine.

I don't know is it apple's bug or what. !!!

If you want to support only portrait mode and only iPhones then you can choose iPhone in Development Info -> devices. and for orientation you can choose Portrait and upside down in Device orientation.

Hope this helps you to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue, just try to use a larger estimatedRowHeight which can contain your content. SDK seems do something wrong when using self-sizing cell.

Comment: Darn, wished it was that easy. Just set `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000.0;` but no dice unfortunately. Same as first screenshot. I feel it has to do with my constraints, especially with the text label (orange in screenshots) - anything you can see wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Just set your row height programatically.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   return rowHieght;
 }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something...that would defeat the purpose of having iOS8 autosize cells for you wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue,
[how-to-add-uiview-in-uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097612/how-to-add-uiview-in-uitableviewcell)

You also have custom cell, so use the following function in customcell class, in your case it is PostCell.m.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // in my case i only had set frame here while my other  
    // declarations were in init function, so it solve my problem
}
```

It solved my same problem, hope it will solve your too, but you have to think it in your own scenario.

Comment: Apologies, not quite following. Are you saying I need to create all my frames in code rather than via Storyboard? Right now, this is what I have in my customcell class. `@implementation PostCell
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    
    [self.usernameLabel setNeedsLayout];
    [self.usernameLabel layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.timestampLabel setNeedsLayout];
    [self.timestampLabel layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.postTextLabel setNeedsLayout];
    [self.postTextLabel layoutIfNeeded];
}
@end`

Comment: I have just shared my problem and experience and hoped that it may help you. . .you can just ignore it if it is useless for you. . . thanks

Comment: I have uploaded my full sample code if you might have the chance to look at it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set your Detail label line 0 then give leading, trailing and bottom constraints.

in `viewDidLoad` method add:

```
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0 //(your estimated row height)
tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

then return the row height in tableview delegate get method cell row height

In Your code

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded]
[cell updateContraintsIfNeeded]
```

are not needed so remove it

Comment: My detail label is set to 0 lines already and I do have leading, trailing, and a bottom constraint. I do have an `estimatedRowHeight` set as well as am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension.` I removed the two lines you recommended, but what do you mean by: "then return the row height in tableview delegate get method cell row height"?

Comment: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
}
this method

Comment: I have updated with full project sample code if might be helpful

Comment: Can you share your sample projecte with me so can i try to solve your problem. Give link for code

Comment: Google Drive links posted above

Comment: Where is the Google Drive Link. I haven't find any line above

Comment: Might be hard to see but definitely there. Recopied  below! WORKING (new project from scratch):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EIkjmOj3ImWXZjVFZMYXZmVGc/view?usp=sharing

NOT WORKING (my project, cleaned up to it's bare minimum)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EIkjmOj3ImMGRNOXU2RlNkWEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have Design your screen in wCompact and hRegular size class and your working copy is design in wAny and hAny Size Class so my be this is problem. I refer the desing our view in wAny and hAny size class so it will compitable in any iPhone or iPad Device. wCompact and hRegular size class is used for iPhone 4,iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 so it not working in iPhone 6 plus

Comment: Google Drive link for sample project which i created for your refrence https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaCijhdNz4cQzBmbGZreU9sazA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. Isn't wC hR compatible with all devices in portrait (including the 6+)? I'll try changing it to wA hA now and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Wow, looks like that fixed it Hiren! Definitely feel free to leave as an answer and I'll happily give you the credit you deserve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for my issue, I set the UILabel font in

```
layoutSubviews:
```

thats causing the problem.

after I moved the code to other place, then it works just fine